# AWS Cloudwatch ALB automatically add to dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I automatically have an application load balancer (ALB) automatically added to my CloudWatch dashboard on provision?

Specifically, when I standup new infrastructure I would like to see the newly created ALB appear inside of CloudWatch without manually having to add it.

I am aware of this repository => [Automated Alarm Creation](https://github.com/thigley986/Lambda-AWS-Automated-Alarm-Creation)

Comment: Trigger a lambda function to add it. Or use a higher level tool like CloudFormation or Terraform to manage the infrastructure.

Comment: What are you using for provisioning?

Comment: @RodrigoM I kick things off from a Jenkins pipeline to get stuff setup.

Comment: @myron-semack do you have any additional insight on this?

Comment: @Woot4Moo And how do you provision AWS in Jenkins?  Do you use CloudFormation?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Lambda functions can be triggered on events, so have a Lambda function to edit the dashboard, and set it up to trigger automatically when resources are provisioned. Personally I’d write it in Python using boto3.